# What is this weird d12 for?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

So I won these d12s at an arcade only to realise they're not normal. Instead of having 1-12 on them, they have some array of numbers from 3-8 or 4-9.
There were red, blue and white ones, and I don't know if all the same coloured ones had the same array of numbers or not.

The two I got is as follows:

- Blue: a four in a circle, three fives in squares, two sixes, two sevens, three eights, and a nine.
- White: as above, but one number lower (from three to eight)

All they (incorrectly) 'knew' was that they're for Dungeons and Dragons which afaik they are not.

[image: the blue and white dice]

Comment: These definitely don't look like anything I've ever seen for D&D.

Answer (score 35):

**These dice are for a game called GOLO Golf Dice.**

[image]

I asked dice guru Kevin Cook at [dicecollector.com](http://www.dicecollector.com/) and he recognized them almost immediately. This game is sold by a company called [Zobmondo](https://www.zobmondo.com/collections/games-for-the-holidays/products/golo-golf-dice-game). It looks like the PDF rules are [free to download](https://www.zobmondo.com/pages/instructions-for-zobmondo-games), but you're missing some dice. In order to play, you're going to need the other seven dice since you roll all nine at the start of your turn.

Comment: The arcade probably got these dice cheap, and are making a huge profit on them, while making them worthless as prizes.

Comment: Someone sent me this game as a Christmas gift five years ago. Recognized them immediately and still have them to this day.

Answer (score 0):

As SocioMatt answered, these are from the game GOLO.  Crystal Caste used to include these in their bulk dice bags, which is probably where the arcade got them.